# For some reason my text box wont clear in c#

Tags: c#, textbox

**To start of I am validating if the user wants to clear the textbox:**

```
    public void CheckSure()
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Visible = true;
    }
```

**Then Form2 opens and I have a selection between yes and no, I pick yes :**

```
    private void YesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        this.Hide();
        f1.Clear();
    }
```

**then it calls the clear method which should clear the textbox:**

```
    public void Clear()
    {
        TextSpace.Text = string.Empty;
    }
```

Using breakpoints I have determined it is definitely getting to the point where it runs the line `TextSpace.Text = string.Empty;` but for some reason the text box does not clear?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your `YesButton_Click` handler is creating a new instance of `Form1`, when it all likely hood it needs a reference to the **current** `Form1`.

Comment: The fact you create a new form and call `Clear` immediately is a bit of a red flag - should you be calling `Clear` on `f2`? Or is it *definitely* `f1`?

Comment: You could also use a MessageBox: if (MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes) TextSpace.Text = string.Empty;

Comment: thank you very much I have settled on ben's one but all of them were useful and have helped me understand why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new instance of Form1. You need to use the current instance.

You can take advantage of the `Form.Owner` property when instantiating Form2:

```
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.Owner = this;
```

Then in Form2, to access Form1 you can call `this.Owner.TextSpace.Clear()`